# What's the easiest way to parse a JSON in Swift 4?

Tags: json, swift

I wrote the following function to do a GET request inside of my macOS  app using Alamofire:

```
func getContent(room: String) -> String {
let scriptUrl = "https://klipped.in/api/\(room)"
Alamofire.request(scriptUrl).responseJSON { response in        
    if let json = response.result.value {
        print("\(json)") // serialized json response
    }
}
return "This should return the value of \"content\" in the json response"
}
```

I now want to parse the json in the most efficient way possible. I googled around ways to do this, but every solution I found seems overly complicated or doesn't run because of type problems.

Is there a simple way in Swift to access the values inside of a JSON without creating a Struct for every response? I'm thinking about something along the lines of:

```
get-json-value(json, "content")
```

That returns the string value of "content" inside of a json and null if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Its duplicate question. Try to use searching. Here is the answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50383222/8417137

Comment: If you are able to read the JSON the most efficient way is `Codable`. If not there is no easy way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON using swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379653/how-to-parse-json-using-swift-4)

Comment: The easiest way is to do some research.

Comment: I had already read the answer and found it strange that for parsing a JSON one had to write so many LOC. I was just asking if there are any libraries that made this process  faster.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to parse a JSON in Swift 4 when using Alamofire is by using

```
getRoomData = JSON as NSDictionary
str = getRoomData["content"] as String
```

See an example at:
[AlamoFire GET api request not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901460/alamofire-get-api-request-not-working-as-expected)

An even Better way is using the [Swifty JSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) library:

```
let json = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
let roomContent = json["content"].string
```